# Order of controls being added to panel, control not showing unless docked

Tags: vb.net, winforms, controls

I imagine this is probably an easy to answer question but for some reason I can't get it to work

```
 Sub New(ByVal Sess As AudioSessionControl2)
    S_Session = Sess

    'Create the panel and position it.
    S_Panel.BackColor = Color.AliceBlue
    S_Panel.Width = 200
    S_Panel.Height = 40
    Dim Position As New Point(6, 19)
    If G_AppSessions.Count > 0 Then
        Position = Point.Add(G_AppSessions.Item(G_AppSessions.Count - 1).SessionPanel.Location, New Point(0, 45))
    End If
    S_Panel.Location = Position

    'Create a label which has the name of the process
    Dim S_PName As New Label
    S_PName.Text = "Test"
    S_PName.Dock = DockStyle.Left
    S_Panel.Controls.Add(S_PName)

    'Create a button to change volume
    Dim S_Save As New Button()
    S_Save.Text = "Save"
    AddHandler S_Save.Click, AddressOf Save_Click
    S_Save.Parent = S_Panel
    S_Panel.Controls.Add(S_Save)

    S_Volume.Parent = S_Panel
    S_PName.Parent = S_Panel

    MainForm.Controls.Add(S_Panel)
    S_Panel.Parent = MainForm.gb_Applications
End Sub
```

The problem is that, the label will show because its docked, but the button won't. It will only show if its docked as well, and thats just not what I want. This is part of a class for creating a dynamic UI, where I can create a number of this class to create a bunch of panels for various things.

Comment: Don't set the Parent property like that.  You are already adding them to the Parent's Controls collection.  Instead of Dock, specifically set the Label and Button's Location property.

Comment: Even if I get rid of the parent property and the dock property, the label shows when I use the location property, but the button doesn't.

Comment: I don't see anywhere where you are setting the label or button position. You probably have them both at 0,0 and the label is on top of the button, obscuring it.  Did you try setting the position of both the controls, making sure they don't overlap?

Comment: Stuff me I'm dumb. They were overlapping. God dammit. I knew it would be something bloody simple, didn't seem right.

Comment: I'll move the comment to the Answer section...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see anywhere where you are setting the label or button position. You probably have them both at 0,0 and the label is on top of the button, obscuring it. Did you try setting the position of both the controls, making sure they don't overlap?